# Clear a C Array

Tags: c, arrays

I have four arrays that are built from reading in a file:

```
file_name[r]        // char array (defined as file_name[10][10])
file_num[r]         // int array
file_scale[r]       // float array
file_source[r]      // int array
```

So I would like to know, how can I clear/empty these arrays so that they are emptied before they are populated?

Comment: C arrays are never "empty". They always have "something". Whether that "something" is *determinate* depends on whether you've written-to (or they have otherwise been initialized in some way) them prior to reading from them. What problem are *really* trying to solve? How to, for example, set all values in an array to `0` ? [See `memset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) as one possible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any global array will be zero initialized when it is declared. For other cases you can use memset from the header `<string.h>` like so:

```
memset(file_name, 0, sizeof(filename));
```

Also for any array you can zero initialize it, when you declare it like so:

```
int a[r] = {0};
```

Although here you explicitly set the value only for the first element, the remaining ones are filled with 0 by standard.

Comment: It is however bad practice to rely on the implicit zero-out of variables with static storage duration. You should initialize all such objects explicitly, to show that you haven't forgotten about the initialization. As for efficiency `static int arr[n];` and `static int arr[n]={0};` generates exactly the same machine code and the variable will be allocated in `.bss` in both cases.

Comment: @Lundin I agree with that, but the info included in my answer is still useful in case you are reading code. I will include the option to zero initilize with decalration

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

what does "empty an array" mean?
an array has always the same size. it cannot be emptied.

so you have to store the acutal length of your data in a separate variable like `int used`.
then its easy to "empty" the array by setting this variable to 0.

if you want to set defaults then you may `memset` the memory.
this is easy if you group the data in a POD-structure.

```
MyType myType;
memset(&myType, 0, sizeof(myType));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set all the array to a definite value, but theyre is no "empty" array.

What you can do is, at the declaration:

```
char file_name[10][10] = {{0}};
int file_num[r] = {0};
float file_scale[r] = {0};
int file_source[r] = {0};
```

so that every variable of every array is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to empty them only when the program starts, how to make them empty depends on the compiler you use, since it depends on the initialization code the compiler puts before executing your code. Usually

```
int someArray[10] = {0};
char charArray[100] = {0};
```

is initializing array to 0. This work also when you declare a local array into a function, that is placed on the stack and reset to 0.

For resetting a previously created array to 0's at runtime there is a standard C function that all compilers I used until now are implementing:

```
memset(myArray,0,sizeof(myArray));
```

of course you need to `#include <string.h>` as already said.

Comment: There is nothing compiler-specific about initialization; it's all in the C language Standard. Automatics are uninitialized, the rest as if 0 had been assigned (unless an explicit initializer says otherwise).

Comment: I am used to program C for microcontrollers, and in that case unfortunately there is no standard initialization code. Until now I had at least three different ways to assure that a global variable becomes initialized or not initialized before the program starts. The three compilers I am speaking of are C18, Hitech and C30. They use different pragmas and/or configurations to have the same result of an initialized variable. I know that is not standard, but that's why I pointed out that is wise to take a look of what the compiler does with initialization.